# Skeleton directory tree in SVN repository

Tags: svn, cakephp

What properties do I need to set on a folder in SVN to ignore all files within a folder tree, except some named exceptions.  I basically want an empty folder tree to be stored in the repo, but any files within them to be ignored for SVN purposes.

Our CakePHP project has a tmp/ folder containing tmp/cache/ and /tmp/logs/ I want to have the folders created when I checkout the project, but not for any files within them to be created/managed via SVN.

In the past I've had empty files called '.empty' as placeholders to ensure that folders were created, but SVN works differently to CVS...

I can see Resource Filters in our Eclipse setup - but I think they're an Eclipse thing rather than an SVN/Subclipse feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `svn:ignore` to the lowest level dirs (logs and cache in this case). i dont think there is a flag like `-f` so youd need to add patterns that would match individual files id you need to commit certain low leve dirs but still need to ignore files in higher level ones.

Comment: Thanks - It would appear that I don't need the .empty files in order to create an empty dir (obviously a CVS quirk); so setting svn:ignore on those files is enough - Thanks!